# Rapid migration of RDS between different regions with MySQL 5.7 for MySQL Aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

What better way to do a quick migration from **RDS MySQL 5.7** from São Paulo/Brazil to **RDS Aurora** in Northern Virginia, from a large database (probably more than 25GB of dump).

But I can not leave the database stopped for more than 3 hours (
or probably less), because this database is production of a company.

Thank you very much in advance.

- In the region of São Paulo no have MySQL Aurora (One of the reasons to do the migration, in addition to the costs being twice as much compared to Northern Virginia)
- RDS may be publicly accessible only during migration if necessary.
- I will not be able to use Multi-AZ. Would it be feasible to use "**AWS Database Migration Service**"?
- I will also have to migrate the instances EC2 and S3 linked to this database, mainly EC2 to avoid latency problems.
- After the migration will be stopped all services in the region of São Paulo.
- The main reasons as I said before is the reduction of costs in the long and short term (will be considered the use of reserved instances) and also performance, and instances EC2 to avoid problems of latency and instability.

Comment: Would it not be possible to have the Brazil instance still running while you do the migration to the USA?

Comment: Yes I can keep the instance running in Brazil

Comment: Then maybe consider a strategy where you temporarily have two separate instances up and running.

Comment: I thought about using ec2 instance exclusively, for example m5.large or higher to dump in Northern Virginia in the following section to send the RDS.

Comment: My fear is that it will take too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a mistake trying to move the database *and* change the engine from MySQL to Aurora at the same time.

Migrate the MySQL 5.7 system now, and convert to Aurora later.  You do not need to ask for trouble, and doing both at the same time is exactly that.

It is not possible to "quickly" migrate a primary database over distance, but it is possible to make the amount of setup time irrelevant, and activation time near zero.

Instead of trying to do a copy, create an RDS cross-region replica of your data, and at the last moment, promote that replica to master.

> **Creating a Read Replica in a Different AWS Region**
>
> With Amazon RDS, you can create a MariaDB, MySQL, or PostgreSQL Read Replica in a different AWS Region than the source DB instance. You create a Read Replica to do the following:
>
> - Improve your disaster recovery capabilities.
> - Scale read operations into an AWS Region closer to your users.
> - Make it easier to migrate from a data center in one AWS Region to a data center in another AWS Region.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.XRgn

It doesn't matter how long it takes for RDS to copy the data and set up the replica, because as soon as it is copied, it starts replicating everything that changed on the master server since the process began.

Once you have verified that everything is correct and consistent, then you [promote a replica](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.Promote).  It is permanently and irrevocably detached from its original upstream instance, and becomes writable.  This is the last thing you do and after the application starts writing to this new database, your original system in São Paulo is obsolete because changes to it will no longer replicate to the new system -- they're permanently isolated.

This arrangement does not require you to establish any networking or make the databases publicly accessible.

And, you can create and destroy multiple replicas to test this process, without disturbing production.